# jQuery validate ignoring its own defaults

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-validate

I am attempting to use `jquery validate` alongside `angularjs`. (*yes, I realize angular has its own validation library. I don't want to use that one*) and am getting some strange behavior when trying to set the defaults for jquery.validate.

I wire it up like this ...

### jquery.validators.setup.js

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
   errorClass: "has-error",
   validClass: "has-success",
   highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass){
      console.log("highlighting: ", element, errorClass, validClass);
   },
   unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass){
      console.log("unhighlighting", element, errorClass, validClass);
   },
   errorPlacement: function(error, element){
      console.log("error on: ", element, error);
   }
});
```

Obviously I will expand these behaviors more, but I need them to at least be triggering first. So my HTML looks like this. I am using `novalidate` to prevent HTML5 validation and only use jquery validate.

### index.html

```
<form role="form" novalidate>
   <div class="form-group">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"
         placeholder="Name"
         required
         minlength="3"
         maxlength="24"
         data-ng-model="Model.Name" />
   </div>
</form>
```

And by all accounts, I think this should work ... but it simply never fires off the validation events. I am trying to make sure they fire off on blur, and I am hoping to avoid needing to wire anything up in my angular controllers.

Comment: There is no such file called `jquery.validators.setup.js` as part of the jQuery Validate plugin.  Also, there is no need for you to manually add the `novalidate` attribute because the plugin dynamically adds it upon initialization.  Finally, have you called the `.validate()` method anywhere?  That needs to be called to initialize the plugin.

Comment: The `jquery.validators.setup.js` is a file I made to initialize the defaults, and it is loaded right after the other jquery.validate files.

Comment: Do you have `$('form').validate()` someplace within your DOM ready event handler?

Comment: No, I'm not really sure where that should go since angular doesn't load things in a linear fashion. Can rules be added or modified after it is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `.validate()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) **must** be called (attached to the `form`) in order to initialize the plugin; typically within the DOM ready event handler and *before* any other jQuery Validate methods are called.  You can put all of your options inside of `.validate()` instead of the `setDefaults` method. `.setDefaults()` is typically only used when you have several forms that share common settings.

Yes, you can modify, add and remove rules dynamically at any time using [the `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

See [the tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for more about the basic usage of this plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // <- DOM ready event
    $('#myform').validate({     // <- initialize the plugin
        // rules, options and callbacks
        errorClass: "has-error",
        validClass: "has-success",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass){
            console.log("highlighting: ", element, errorClass, validClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass){
            console.log("unhighlighting", element, errorClass, validClass);
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            console.log("error on: ", element, error);
        }
    });
});
```

**Please note that since you've over-ridden all of the standard callbacks with `console.log`, the default functionality will be gone.**

Comment: Well, I'm trying what you've said, but it doesn't seem to let me add rules after `validate` is called. I've prepared a demo to elaborate a bit more where the issue is: http://jsbin.com/vicot/1/edit

Comment: I want to avoid putting anything in the `validate` method unless __absolutely__ necessary. The goal here is to declare as much of the validation logic as possible in the HTML attribute directives. The only situation that should need javascript defining is the remote behavior, basically.

Comment: I think I am starting to see what you are talking about, thank you. I've gotten it to start firing, but the whole issue with adding rules dynamically is continuing to fail. Is this trying to add them at the wrong places?

Comment: Essentially, I need to wire up more complicated remote validation logic. That is the end goal. I have situations where the remote validation needs to function against 2 or more fields at a time, and the standard jquery validation library doesn't do this in HTML directives. So I need to be capable of adding the rule dynamically. That was the ultimate goal of this whole experiment.

Comment: Though now that I think of it, you have already answered my original question. Would it be okay if I award credit for this one, and then open a new one for the specific issue involving the remote feature? I can link it here too, if you're interested in the points.

Comment: Hey, thank you again for your help - this is the new topic I've made to follow up with the remote issue. I've awarded you the points for this one. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414251/jquery-validate-creating-remote-validation-with-angular-directive